# Azure Function - Replace the AzureWebJobsStorage value in local.settings.json with Azure Key Vault connection string

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-durable-functions

I am implementing the Azure Key Vault Managed Identity in Azure Durable Function.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private const string localSettingsJson = "local.settings.json";

    private IConfigurationBuilder GetConfiguration(FunctionsHostBuilderContext context) => new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(context.ApplicationRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile(localSettingsJson, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();
        var configBuilder = GetConfiguration(context);

        DefaultAzureCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "61063c32-379d-4e9d-8977-4b826c2bc50a" });
        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://storageaccount.vault.azure.net/"), credential);
        configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());

        IConfigurationRoot config = configBuilder.Build();
        var keyVaultConnectionStringValue = config["storageaccount-connectionstring"];

        //Getting the connection string value in keyVaultConnectionStringValue.

        var services = builder.Services;
        services.ConfigureAutoMapper();
    }
}
```

**Orchestration.cs**

```
public class Orchestration
{
    [FunctionName("Orchestrator")]
    public async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

I am getting the connection string value in keyVaultConnectionStringValue variable. Now I want to replace keyVaultConnectionStringValue variable value in the **local.settings.json** file => Values section => `AzureWebJobsStorage` section value. Current value is "`UseDevelopmentStorage=true`" and I want to replace with Azure Key Vault connection string value.

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", // Replace "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" value with Azure Key Vault connection string value.
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "WorkflowConfiguration": {
    "Name": "Lilly"
  }
}
```

**NOTE: I don't want to use the Environment Variable.**

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please let us know if you have tried to add the connection string value in your local settings.json or not , and also as mentioned in this article https://www.techwatching.dev/posts/azure-functions-custom-configuration "if you use a trigger that needs a secret (the connection string of an EventHub trigger for instance), you have no other choice than to use a key vault reference. But for everything else you are good to go with Azure Key Vault configuration provider."

Comment: I tried to add the connection string value dynamically from the code to local.settings.json file but not getting reflected in it. I was look at that article but no use. As I am already using the azure key vault managed identity and getting the connection string value in the code. Just I need to override it in the local.settings.json file. Any link or help is really appreciated,.

Comment: Could you please have a look into this and let us know if it helps 
Article: where it shows [getting Key Vault Secrets in Azure Functions](https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b) & this open GitHub issue :https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/717#issuecomment-507520958

Comment: why would you like to replace the connection string in the local setting file  ? the point of using key vault is not to have to store secret locally